# 1 transaction that uses 2 merchant accounts

Tags: php, authorize.net

I need to setup a bill pay system to allow for 1 transaction that uses 2 merchant accounts.  For example, 1 merchant account is attached to the client receiving the funds let’s say $30 dollars charge for the purchase, and attached we will charge let’s say a $3 bill pay fee attached to the bill pay service provider.  So the funds need to go to 2 separate merchant accounts but we want the user/client of the bill pay system to be charged only once on their credit card.

Example:
user have to pay $33 one time,  30 for purchase and $3 for bill pay service provider.
The customer should get 1 transaction, 1 receipt  on their credit card.

Is this possible with AIM authorize.net?

Comment: As mentioned below, this isn't possible with Authorize.Net.  You can do this with Amazon FPS, but you don't get full control over the checkout process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont be possible with any service provider. Its a bank processing issue. Each merchants transaction will appear as a separate item on the credit card bill.

You would have to take the whole $33 amount into your account, and then pay the 3rd party the $30 (or vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

No. Authorize.Net is associated with one merchant account only. All payments go directly into that merchant account. If you wish to accomplish this whomever receives the payment will need to then make payment to the other party.

Comment: now if i want to check the balance before making payment can i? how?

Comment: What balance do you want to check?

Comment: i was trying to check the credit card balance, but i think thatz not possible