# payment to multiple merchant accounts

Tags: authorize.net, payflowpro

I have a client that has 3 "foundations", each with their own merchant account.
The client wants a single donation form that will allow someone to donate to any or all of those
foundations.

Example 1:
- $40 to foundation A
- $50 to foundation B
- $10 to foundation C.

Example 2:
- $100 to foundation A

Is this possible with Authorize.Net or Payflow Pro, and if so is it possible to do it 
all programatically, whithout the client having to mess with anything?
Also would it work with recurring billing?

Thanks!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319994/1-transaction-that-uses-2-merchant-accounts

Answer (score 1):

You can use paypal parallel payment for this

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do two, or more, payments at one time. What you need to do is send one partial payment over and then do a separate transaction for each remaining balance. You need to keep a few things in mind like:

- You don't want to process any more
  payments if the first payment is
  declined
- If subsequent payments are
  declined you need to remember to void
  the previous payments. If not you risk
  getting chargebacks.

Comment: Is this something you have done before? This guy is saying the API is designed to pay one merchant, and you need to use Mass Payment to allocate them... https://www.x.com/message/170664

And what is parallel payments exactly? https://www.x.com/blogs/easypaypalwithphp/2010/01/26/exploring-parallel-payments-with-php-with-a-sample-application
Sounds like what I'm looking for but the description isn't totally clear to me. Any ideas? I appreciate the advice!

Comment: Also the Adaptive Payments documentation seems to suggest you can pay multiple "receivers" in a single transaction: https://www.x.com/community/ppx/documentation#ap

Answer (score 0):

i hv asked such question once
[1 transaction that uses 2 merchant accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319994/1-transaction-that-uses-2-merchant-accounts)

and the answer is 
This wont be possible with any service provider.